# Can't open 2 routable modals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a social media application which is similar to Instagram. I need to use the concept of routable modal for better UX following these articles:

https://dev.to/unorthodev/how-to-make-routable-modals-in-react-with-react-router-3hgp

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-routable-modal-ubkpar?file=src/Modal.jsx

But if I open a second modal inside of an existing modal, when I click backward (Or call history.goBack()) the first modal will reload completely. Any clues?

1. I open a card on the home screen (Card is the (1) modal)
2. I click on the "Click here to open test modal" to open the second modal (This is the (2) modal)
3. I click go back, and the (1) modal is reloaded.

Expected:
The (1) modal shouldn't be reloaded

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Wait, is your example sandbox code ***your*** code? It's all Angular code. Other than this, it's clear that the modals are open when the component mounts, if you are navigating back and components remount then I'd say this is expected behavior since you are coupling the modal being open to the route it's associated to being matched. Can you [edit] to include a *relevant* [mcve] and running sandbox if you feel it's necessary, and clarify what you mean by "open a second modal inside of an existing modal"? It seems odd to allow that.

Comment: oops, sorry man, I attached the wrong example, will update. Ideally, you can imagine that
1. I open a user profile on the home screen (user profile is the (1) modal)
2. I find a photo on their profile and open it (user's photo is the (2) modal)
3. I click go back, and the (1) modal is reloaded

Expected:
The (1) modal shouldn't be reloaded

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand what the issue is from your codesandbox code. It appears to correctly navigate back when the modal is closed/dismissed. I'm unable to repro two modals open at the same time, or to get more than two "modals" in the history stack to navigate back to a previously opened "modal". Can you clarify the reproduction steps?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi, I updated the example, you can follow the step above to reproduce the behavior

Answer (score 0):

Since the modal opening is coupled to the route being matched and rendered, when the UI navigates from `"/test"` back to `"/contact/:name"` the route will be matched and render the routed content, `Modal` in this case.

You say you don't want the modal to be reloaded, that can be fixed by conditionally rendering the JSX or not, but then there's another issue where the URL path is ***still*** `"/contact/:name"` and nothing is rendered. What I suspect you really want is for the UI to not have any `background` route state and for the UI to navigate back to `"/contacts"` where the array of contact cards are rendered.

What I think will resolve both these issues is to listen to what the navigation action was. If the navigation action was a `"POP"` then issue another imperative back navigation action to get the UI back to `"/contacts"`, otherwise, assume it was a `"PUSH"` or `"REPLACE"` and that the modal should be rendered.

Effect

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (history.action === "POP") {
    history.goBack();
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    setShowCard(true);
  }, 1000);
}, []);
```

Full component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from './Card';

const Modal = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState(false);

  const closeModal = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    history.goBack();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (history.action === "POP") {
      history.goBack();
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowCard(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-75 w-full h-screen z-10 flex items-center justify-center">
      <span
        className="inline-block absolute top-0 right-0 mr-4 mt-4 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={closeModal}
      >
        <svg
          class="w-6 h-6 text-white"
          fill="currentColor"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
          />
        </svg>
      </span>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        {showCard && <Card />}
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/test',
            state: { background: location },
          }}
        >
          <h1 className="text-lg font-medium text-gray-600 mt-2">
            Click here to open test modal
          </h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: @thanhtran3k Welcome. Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: Hi man, sadly, both of the modals are closed, I just want to close the latest modal without reload the parent modal

Comment: @thanhtran3k How many modals do you want open at any one time? When the modals are coupled to a matched route, and the route no longer matches, the modal will be unmounted. Can you clarify what UX (user experience) you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: maybe at least 2 - 3 modals at a time

Comment: @thanhtran3k Then I think you should de-couple modals from routes and just track which are open... ***or*** ... re-organize route paths such that parent routes remain matched and mounted while nested routes are also match/mounted and rendering their modals. Does this make sense?

Comment: it worth a try, thanks man